# undefined reference to [class::function] / undefined reference to typeinfo for [class]

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a base class defined with 3 pure virtual functions:

```
class Baseclass
{
public:
    virtual ~Baseclass() {};
    virtual void getSomething(std::vector<uint8_t>& something) const = 0;
    virtual uint8_t classLength() const = 0;
}
```

And from that I derive 2 other classes

```
class DerivedA : public Baseclass
{
public:
    DerivedA();
    ~DerivedA();
    bool setParamA(const std::vector<uint8_t> value);
    bool setParamB(const std::vector<uint8_t> value);
    void getSomething(std::vector<uint8_t>& something) const;
    uint8_t classLength() const;
private:
    uint8_t mParamA;
    uint8_t mParamB;
}
```

The second class is analog to the first.

This compiles and works perfectly for my unit tests (regular allocation, no pointers).

Now i try to integrate this (it is compiled as a library) in the rest of my code like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Baseclass> object;
object = std::make_shared<DerivedA>(); // 1
std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedA>(object)->setParamA(...) // 2
```

Compilation goes perfectly but linking gives following errors:

undefined reference to typeinfo for [class] (line 1)
undefined reference to [class::function] (line 2)

on this command

```
g++-4.7  -o ../Deliv/GnuDebug/ClassesTest ../Deliv/GnuDebug/buildsupport/cppunit/mainCB.o   -pthread  ../../../../../../3rdparty/libcppunit/obj/native-gcc/libcppunit/src/cppunit/.libs/libcppunit.a ../../../Classes/Deliv/GnuDebug/libClasses.a
```

Another strange thing is that it only produces this error for 1 of the derived classes and that 1 of the derived classes has worked in the above construction for allocation of the shared_ptr

I have no clue what could be wrong here, if anyone could point me in the right direction i will be eternally grateful

**edit with solution:**

I found the solution to my problem so for further reference:

Setup:

```
Baseobject, DerivedA, DerivedB -> libObjects.a
Functionality using DerivedA, DerivedB -> libFunctionality.a
TestFunctionality using Functionality -> Error
```

Problem:

That the linker was trying to link to libFunctionality before It knew libObjects and therefore giving errors.

Solution:

Change the order in which the libraries get linked.

Strange behavior:

I only got errors for DerivedA, not for DerivedB. If I would comment out the code using DerivedA, TestFunctionality would compile and run without errors.
Has anyone got a clue to why this is ?

And can someone verify my explanation for correctness and perhaps point me to some article explaining this problem ?

Comment: Could you post a complete, compilable example to demonstrate the problem? Does your real code have missing `;` after the class definitions? Are you implementing `DerivedA::~DerivedA`, `DerivedA::getSomething` and `DerivedA::classLength`? Are those implementations inline? If not, are you linking with the translation unit that contains those implementations? Which class(es) and function(s) do the errors refer to?

Comment: I've just noticed "it is compiled as a library". Are you linking with that library?

Comment: Your example code is correct in spirit and can be [made to work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4a77506e650c1a649513c404ee379cb8), so that's not the problem. You might want to explain e.g. how you are trying to compile your program to give a chance of finding the issue.

Comment: @MikeSeymour A compilable example could be hard as it quite a big project but I'll try in a little while. The ; is't forgotten in the real class :). I am linking to the library as it works for 1 of the derived classes. The implementations are not inline. the errors refer to Derived (first one) and Derived::setParamA(unsigned short const&) (second one)

Comment: There are only 2 pure virtual functions in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the function `bool DerivedA::setParamA(const std::vector<uint8_t> value);` and not only have a declaration of it.

Comment: There are implementations for all functions present

Comment: @Minion91: [I couldn't foresee it.](http://sscce.org/) and seemingly wasted my time on a thought that [could have been avoided](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry for that, nice link though, bookmarked